# How to make a specific job wait for a slave indefinitely?

Tags: jenkins

**Problem :**

A certain task often crashes the slave, which then should reboot (sometimes it doesn't). If the reboot fails, it may take a week until someone reboots the computer. Then the build which failed couldn't archive the artifacts.

**Idea to solve it (if there is a better one please tell me) :**

To have a task always launch after this one which checks if the artifacts failed to be made (I have a way to check it), and then wait forever until the slave becomes available again, to archive the artifacts.

I know it's possible to do such for every job, but I cannot find how to do it for a specific job.

Comment: I understand that you have a master and a slave jenkins. On the slave jenkins you have builds running. Your master shall wait until those are finished before starting new ones? Can you be more specific about the term "forever"?

Comment: @michaelbahr edited it!! Hopes it's more specific

Comment: thats better, thank you! I found something that im putting together right now

Comment: If you could also tell me how you found it, I'd really appreciate : you have no idea how many hours I spent searching that! I must not use the correct keyword or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to actually fix what crashes your server.

But for now you can add another job:

1. In Jenkins create a "New Item".
2. Make this a freestyle project.
3. In the "Build Trigger" section, select "Build after other projects are built".
4. Here you select the other job that causes the slave to crash.
5. Afterwards add you monitoring-and-restart-script as a build step.